# Can noindex tags on several pages affect the overall SEO or ranking on Google?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, noindex

Some SEO Gurus assured me that `noindex` attributes are good to devalue the unimportant pages.

When I asked in the moz Q and A, they're quite sure that having `noindex` on the bulk of the articles on the website can harm overall SEO ranking.

Which is true?

Comment: Is this the moz q and a you are referring to?  [Can too many "noindex" pages compared to "index" pages be a problem? | SEO Q&A | Moz](https://moz.com/community/q/are-too-many-noindex-pages-compared-with-index-pages-be-a-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Both.

If you add `NOINDEX` to some articles, they won't help you with SEO because they won't be seen by search engines.

If most of your articles are not seen by search engines, then your website is missing opportunities to rank and bring organic traffic.

If your question is if adding `NOINDEX` to some articles will hurt the rankings of the other articles or the website in general, then no - it will be as if those articles with `NOINDEX` didn't exist, so no impact on the rest.

Comment: oh, you cleared my doubt. Are you really sure that any percentage of no index tag have no affect over SEO?